Which copyrights hold for questions, answers and comments posted on stackexchange?
Could someone please reference the terms and conditions or any  legal basis which allows the owner of stackexchange to process the content of our questions, answers and comment for their own aims, e.g. to sell the texts to companies with an interest to train their Large Language Models, thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Stackexchange meta, not philosophy meta. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399619, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430192 and dozens of questions on the topic on SE meta

It's not just about or primarily about CC-BY-SA. The terms of service for the stackexchange network are here

Subscriber Content
You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations, and product feedback (collectively, “Content”) that you provide to the public Network (collectively, “Subscriber Content”), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you as reasonably necessary to, for example (without limitation):

Provide, maintain, and update the public Network
Process lawful requests from law enforcement agencies and government agencies
Prevent and address security incidents and data security features, support features, and to provide technical assistance as it may be required
Aggregate data to provide product optimization

This means that you cannot revoke permission for Stack Overflow to publish, distribute, store and use such content and to allow others to have derivative rights to publish, distribute, store and use such content. The CC BY-SA 4.0 license terms are explained in further detail by Creative Commons, and the license terms applicable to content are explained in further detail here. You should be aware that all Public Content you contribute is available for public copy and redistribution, and all such Public Content must have appropriate attribution.
As stated above, by agreeing to these Public Network Terms you also agree to be bound by the terms and conditions of the Acceptable Use Policy incorporated herein, and hereby acknowledge and agree that any and all Public Content you provide to the public Network is governed by the Acceptable Use Policy.

To sum up, everyone including Stack Overflow can use your content according to the CC-BY-SA license, but Stack Overflow additionally grants itself (by the terms of service) a license to commercially exploit your content in any way. That includes training LLMs.

StackExachange uses a Creative Commons copyright license. The current version is 4.0. This page contains the legal code.
This page contains the following summary:

You are free to:
Share — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format for any purpose, even commercially.
Adapt — remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose, even commercially.
The licensor cannot revoke these freedoms as long as you follow the license terms.
Under the following terms:
Attribution — You must give appropriate credit , provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.
ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.
No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.
Notices:
You do not have to comply with the license for elements of the
material in the public domain or where your use is permitted by an
applicable exception or limitation.
No warranties are given. The license may not give you all of the
permissions necessary for your intended use. For example, other rights
such as publicity, privacy, or moral rights may limit how you use the
material.


This isn't really what gives them the legal right to exploit our content. Stackexchange is legally allowed to do so according to the terms of service without complying with CC-BY-SA. See my answer.

At least as regards ChatGPT, all the content published in Stack Exchange falls under the category of "publicly available information that is freely and openly available on the Internet." According to https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7842364-how-chatgpt-and-our-foundation-models-are-developed:

What type of information is used to teach ChatGPT?
As noted above, ChatGPT and our other services are developed using (1) information that is publicly available on the internet, (2) information that we partner with third parties to access, and (3) information that our users or human trainers and researchers provide or generate. This article focuses on the first set: information that is publicly available on the internet.
For this set of information, we only use publicly available information that is freely and openly available on the Internet – for example, we do not seek information that we know is behind paywalls or from the “dark web.” We apply filters and remove information that we do not want our models to learn from or output, such as hate speech, adult content, sites that primarily aggregate personal information, and spam. We then use the information to teach our models.
As mentioned in the previous section, ChatGPT does not copy or store training information in a database. Instead, it learns about associations between words and concepts, and those learnings help the model update its numbers/weights. The model then uses those weights to predict and generate new content in response to a user request. It does not “copy and paste” training information – much like a teacher who has learned from lots of prior study and can explain things because she has learned the relationships between concepts, but doesn’t store copies of the materials in her head..

